# Anyone know how to resolve "Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'" error with Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to develop followers for an app.  Here is the code I have to retrieve the current authenticated users (minus the logged in user) and create a local list.  I also have code to write a followers list to the Firebase but just this code (step 1) is throwing errors.

```
func retrieveUsers() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            let users = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.user.removeAll()
            for (_, value) in users {
                if let uid = value["uid"] as! String {
                    if uid != Auth.auth().currentuser.uid {
                        let userToShow = User()
                        if let firest_name = value["firest_name"] as? String {
                            userToShow.userId = uid
                            self.user.append(userToShow)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
    }
```

```
if let uid = value["uid"] as! String {
```

is throwing **Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'** which I really do not understand.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're casting your `users` constant to type `[String: AnyObject]`. In the loop where you're iterating the dictionary you try to create a constant `uid` assuming that `value` is a dictionary with String keys. However you don't know that since it is `AnyObject` as per your previous cast. `AnyObject` doesn't respond to `subscript(_:)` hence your error.

If you know that `snapshot.value` is indeed a `[String: Dictionary]` then you can change your cast type or you could cast `value` to this type.

Also note that using a force cast is a bad practice and can lead to nasty and hard to find bugs.

Comment: Ahhhhh.  but when I recast it to   let users = snapshot.value as! [String: Dictionary<<#Key: Hashable#>, Any>], what do I use as the #Key and Hashable?

Comment: Well whatever your Key and Hashable are supposed to be ? Can you not find a documentation for this API ? Also please stop using force casts :D